# Register a method in another class to a static class?

Tags: c#, .net, methods, static

Is there any possibilities to register a method in another class to a `static` class in C#, so that i can call that class using the `static` class name.

**Example**

```
public static class StaticClass
{

 }


public static class Sample
{
public static string method1()
{return "";}  
}
```

I want to call like this,`StaticClass.method1()`.

**First of all,IS IT VALID or Not?** or **Is there any possible way to do that?**

Comment: What's the problem with `Sample.method1()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all,IS IT VALID or Not?

Sure it's valid; just not the way you're portraying it.

> Is there any possible way to do that?

One approach would be to build a method on `StaticClass` called `method1`. Maybe you want to encapsulate some default behavior:

```
public static class StaticClass
{
    public static string method1()
    {
        // do what you need

        Sample.method1();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't derive one class from a static class, and static classes can't derive from anything other than `object` (and even that has to be implicit).

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks. I feel pretty stupid about that. Sorry friend.